# Pushing A New WatchKit Controller Immediately After Popping Another Always Fails

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit

OK. It's easy enough to do this in classic iOS, but WatchKit doesn't give any blocks/closures, and there isn't a choice between with/without animation.

I have a root controller that has a list of options. Touching one of the options (on either the watch or the phone) will close any currently open controller ([popToRootController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkinterfacecontroller/1619535-poptorootcontroller)), then immediately, [push a new one](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkinterfacecontroller/1619532-pushcontroller).

More or less, like so:

```
self.popToRootController()
self.pushController(withName: "IKANHAZCHEEZEBURGR", context: nil)
```

The problem is that there isn't enough time between the calls, and there's no lambda for me to execute a semaphore or push the controller.

If I step through with the debugger, it happens, no problem.
If I just hit "run," it no work.
This is what is known as [a "heisenbug"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug).

I guess I could do a one-shot timer, but that seems to be such a hideous hack that it may actually cause a disruption of The Force.

Any better ideas? What am I missing?

I know there's a TON of answers for iOS. They don't do me a whole lot of good, here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I succumbed to The Dark Side, and did the timer hack. It works. I need to give it around 0.4 seconds per open controller.

Here's an approximation of what I did:

```
self.popToRootController()
let _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.4, target: self, selector: #selector(self.timerCallback(_:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

func timerCallback(_ timer: Timer) {
    if let timerIndex = timer.userInfo as? Int {
        if 0 <= timerIndex {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {self.pushController(withName: "IKANHAZCHEEZEBURGR", context: nil)}
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:** I do want to mention that, even though this "solves" my issue, the issue that this issue is even an issue is an issue. My design was bad, and I am redesigning the basic navigation. I'll be using a page-based approach, instead of this hierarchical design.

On general principle, if I need to hack to make it work, I'm usually better off doing it a different way.